# How to access bound this in js-interop?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I am trying to use [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) library from withing Dart.

However, I need to provide various functions that are called by *React* with `this` bound to some javascript object. I know, that I can provide Dart callbacks to javascript code using js interop `Callback` class, however I have no idea, how to access javascript `this` within these callbacks.

Could you please help me find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the optional named parameter `withThis` on `Callback` creation. With that, the javascript `this` will be added as first parameter when the dart function will be called. Something like :

```dart
var func = (jsThis, arg1) {
  // do the job with jsThis
};
new Callback.many(func, withThis: true);
```